# Ubuntu 17.10 custom top bar and dual monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, top-bar

Clock is placed in middle. I want it in left. Because middle is distracting me. And when i using dual monitor top bar's only displaying one of it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the gnome-extensions. [Move Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/) is one which works fine, and moves the clock to the left of status bar.